# What does "trace of point $(x_0, y_0)$ to $f(x,y)$ for the plane $y=y_0$" mean?

Tags: tangent-line

What does "*trace* of point $(x_0, y_0)$ to $f(x,y)$ for the plane $y=y_0$" mean?

What's a trace in this case?

As given here:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TangentPlanes.aspx

Comment: fix $y_0 = y$ which is a plane, and vary $x$ starting from $x_0$

Comment: @IntegrateThis Is "trace" the common term for this kind of thing?

Comment: read this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/PartialDerivInterp.aspx

Comment: @IntegrateThis Perhaps it can be interpreted as a section as well? Like in conic sections.

Comment: I think the notion of intersecting a solid with a plane is a helpful concept to spend some time pondering about, in this case fixing $y$ or $x$ ties in with partial derivatives. The pictures on that link I gave was good.